# Will the write() system call block further operation till read() is involved, or vice versa?

Tags: networking, system-calls

Written as part of a TCP/IP client-server:

Server:

```
write(nfds,data1,sizeof(data1));
usleep(1000);
write(nfds,data2,sizeof(data2));
```

Client:

```
read(fds,s,sizeof(s));
printf("%s",s);
read(fds,s,sizeof(s));
printf("%s",s);
```

Without `usleep(1000)` between the two calls to `write()`, the client prints data1 twice. Why is this?

Background:

I am doing a Client-Server program where the server has to send two consecutive pieces of information after their acquisition, via the network (socket); `nfds` is the file descriptor we get from `accept()`. 
In the client side, we receive these information via `read`; here `fds` is the file descriptor obtained via `socket()`.

My issue is that when I am NOT using the `usleep(1000)` between the `write()` functions, the client just prints the info represented by data1 twice, instead of printing data1 and then data2. When I put in the `usleep()` it's fine. Exactly WHY is this happening? Is `write()` blocking the operation till the buffer is read or is `read()` blocking the operation till info is written into the buffer? Or am I completely off the page?

Comment: You don't give enough context for a meaningful answer.

Comment: What do you need ? I can provide it.

Comment: always check the return codes of read and write to see how many characters they transferred.

Comment: Would be interesting to see how `fds` is assigned (open, connect, etc.) and any `ioctl`s or `fcntl`s that have been applied to it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I am working on a data acquisition system; the main part is the circuit which actually gathers and processes the data; the Client-Server I am putting in place is fairly simple; I have not used fcntl() or ioctl() in this program. This doubt is more or less a theoretical one.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have used socket programming; so no open associated with it; AF_INET is the address family used.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the actual `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept` and `connect` calls in your code. You may change any sensitive information about your site or your application (e.g., host names or addresses, port numbers, variable names) but, of course, not options, flags, types and protocols, etc. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. Also, the bigger picture is that it would be much easier to diagnose this problem if, as meuh suggested, you modified your programs to report the return codes from `read` and `write`.

Comment: That usleep should not help: you aren't checking the return value of read() in the client, so it is likely returning 0 because the second data has not arrived yet, and your buffer still contains the first data so you print it twice.  This can happen even without that usleep, and the usleep should guarantee that it happens.  You might even only get *part* of data1 from the read(), so you always need to check the return value to see how much data you *did* get.

Comment: @FebinSunny, this seems like purely a programming question, so it may end up getting migrated to Stack Overflow.  If you have questions specific to Unix/Linux, we'd be happy to see you ask them here.  :)

Comment: @psusi `read()` will not 'return 0 because the second data has not arrived'. In this cicrumstance it will either block, in blocking mode, or return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` in non-blocking mode.

Comment: @EJP, ahh right.. 0 == EOF.. I suppose what I meant to say is that just because the other end sent x bytes in one call does not mean the other will read the same number of bytes in one call.

Answer (score 0):

You are making several false assumptions. There is nothing in TCP that guarantees that one send equals one receive. There is a lot of buffering, at both ends, and there are deliberate delays in sending to as to coalesce packets (the Nagle algorithm). When you call `read()`, or `recv()` and friends, you need to store the result into a variable and examine it for each of the following cases:

- -1: an error: examine/log/print `errno`, or `strerror()`, or call `perror()`, and in most cases close the socket and exit the reading loop.
- 0: end of stream; the owner has closed the connection; close the socket and exit the reading loop.
- a positive value but less than you expected: keep reading and accumulate the data until you have everything you need.
- a positive value that is more than you expected: process the data you expected, and save the rest for next time.
- exactly what you expected: process the data, discard it all, and repeat. This isn the easy case, and it is rare, but it is the only case you are currently programming for.

Don't add sleeps into networking code. It doesn't solve problems, it only delays them.

Comment: I have used condition based checking for read()  & write(), aong with perror().

Using usleep() solved the issue the code had. Can you say why "data1" was read twice and then "data1" &"data2" (as needed) once the usleep() was added ?'